# Unknown process consuming 16 cores in

Tags: 14.04

On my ubuntu server, an unknown process is consuming all 16 of 40 cores. It starts again after I kill it.

- Script: `ld-linux-x86-64-so.2`
- Full command `$HOME/.ttp/a/stak/ld-linux-x86-64-so.2 --library-path $HOME/.ttp/a/stak/`

Here is output of my `htop` command.

[image]
[image]

I tried to kill it but it starts again. It is slowing down my server. Kindly guide me how to permanently stop this process.

Comment: Monero miner: https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak Looks like your systems pwned.

Comment: It's probably malware. There's no reason why you'd have libraries in that location anyway. Nuke it from orbit and restore from backups. That's the only sane way to deal with malware - it's difficult to detect other backdoors that may be left.